# The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it. DISPATCHER NOT working

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception, dispatcher

OK this is a very common problem:

```
imgUser.Source = ocBitmaps[iComboBoxSelectedItem];<---collection of images
```

This throws an error because it is not run on the UI thread. Additionally, if I add a dispatcher:

```
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>imgUser.Source = ocBitmaps[iComboBoxSelectedItem]; }));
```

It still doesn't work, I get the same result if I use a dispatcher with the 2-step version:

```
BitmapImage img = ocBitmaps[iComboBoxSelectedItem];
System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() => { imgUser.Source = img; }));
```

Every answer I've seen to this problem seems to have the dispatcher as a solution. Why doesn't it work here?

Additional Information: I'm working in a library connected to my MainView project, but i don't think it's important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK I've got the solution and I am quite happy about it since it's a general solution that can be used other times and perhaps be useful to other people.
I solved the problem using the dispatcher not on the instruction causing the exception but going back in the stack, applying the dispatcher and seeing if that solves the problem.

In my case therefore I had to apply the dispatcher to the whole routine containing the aforementioned instruction causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that your problem is that `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` returns the dispatcher for the current thread (or creates on for this thread, see the [msdn page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.currentdispatcher%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). You probably want to use the dispatcher for the UI thread.

- If you are using WPF, then the simplest way is to get a reference to a WPF `Control` and use its `Dispatcher` property, which should be the dispatcher for the UI thread.
- In WinForms, I would recommend using Invoke: `winFormsControl.Invoke((Action)(() => { ... }));`. Similarly to `Dispatcher`, you can use `BeginInvoke` to run it asynchronously.

Comment: If you read what I have written I have said that I am in WPF and am using the dispatcher on the control already

Comment: I apologize, however you did not mention WPF anywhere I can see. You did mention Dispatcher, but as I understand, that is technically viable in WinForms as well. Additionally, future viewers may find having information about both frameworks helpful. Finally, your code samples all seem to use the static `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` property, which is not using the `Control`'s `Dispatcher`, but rather the current thread's `Dispatcher`.

Comment: Not a biggie but as far as I know the programming language has not to be mentioned anywhere but in the tags. Thanks for the other info

Comment: WPF/WinForms aren't languages, they're frameworks. Both should work with any .NET-compatible language (though some are harder to use), plus XAML for WPF. In short, C# (from the tag) does not specify WPF/WinForms, so I provided both for reference. @Patrick Did the suggested WPF fix help?

Comment: So, using `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` property while on a non-UI thread prevented the cross-thread exception?

Comment: Exactly. This is something I didn't know but that problem occurred several times to me.